# Extracting username from UNIX path using Regex

Tags: regex, unix

I need to get a username from an Unix path with this format:
/home/users/myusername/project/number/files

I just want "myusername" I've been trying for almost a hour and I'm completely clueless.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that the home directory name isn't necessarily the same as the user name. To get the real user name from the home directory, you need to iterate over the `passwd` database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(\/home\/users\/)([^\/]+)
```

The 2nd capture group (index 1) will be `myusername`

Answer (score 5):

Maybe just `/home/users/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*)/.*`?

Note that the critical part `[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*` has to contain all valid characters for unix usernames. I took from [here](http://unix.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.unix.bsd.openbsd.misc/2004-04/0099.html), that a username should only contain digits, characters, dashes and underscores.

Also note that the extracted username is not the whole matching, but the first group (indicated by `(...)`).

Comment: He says his path is `/home/users/myusername/project/number/files`. Your regexp may only find `users`.

Comment: @TK: You're completely right. But I think he'll be clever enough to adapt it to his needs.

Comment: You also need to be careful about anchoring. Any user can create the file `/tmp/home/users/root/project/number/files` :-)

Answer (score 2):

The best answer to this depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you want to know the user who owns that file then you can use the stat command, this unfortunately has slightly different syntax dependant on the operating system however the following two commands work

Max OS/X

```
stat -f '%Su' /home/users/myusername/project/number/files
```

Redhat/Fedora/Centos

```
stat -c '%U' /home/users/myusername/project/number/files
```

If you really do want the string following /home/users then the either of the Regexes provided above will do that, you could use that in a bash script as follows (Mac OS/X)

```
USERNAME=$(echo '/home/users/myusername/project/number/files' | \
  sed -E -e 's!^/home/users/([^/]+)/.*$!\1!g')
```

Answer (score 1):

Check http://rubular.com/r/84zwJmV62G. The first match, not the entire match, is the username.

Answer (score 1):

in a bourne shell something like :

```
string="/home/users/STRINGWEWANT/some/subdir/here"
echo $string | awk -F\/ '{print $3}'
```

would be one option, assuming its always the third element of the path. There are more lightweight that use only the shell builtins :

```
echo ${x#*users/}
```

will strip out everything up to and including 'users/'

```
echo ${y%%/*}
```

Will strip out the remainder.

So to put it all together :

```
export path="/home/users/STRINGWEWABT/some/other/dirs"
export y=`echo ${path#*users/}` && echo ${y%%/*}
STRINGWEWABT
```

Also checkout the bash manpage and search for "Parameter Expansion"